# TopShelf Running As Service Doesn't Pass The Arguments

Tags: c#, topshelf

When running the code below using Powershell/cmd

`DataReplicator.exe run -h:localhost -d:networkdatabase -U:root -pwd:testpwd -tbl:testtable -dbms:1 -p:3306`.

Its running as expected but when I run this as a service, the arguments are not passed to my constructor but on their default values. What am I doing wrong here? Do I need to do more? The code below:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var exitCode = HostFactory.Run(x =>
    {
        x.AddCommandLineDefinition("h", v => hostName = v); 
        x.AddCommandLineDefinition("p", v => port = Int32.Parse(v));                                                                             
        x.AddCommandLineDefinition("U", v => user = v);
        x.AddCommandLineDefinition("pwd", v => password = v);
        x.AddCommandLineDefinition("d", v => dbName = v);
        x.AddCommandLineDefinition("tbl", v => tableName = v);
        x.AddCommandLineDefinition("dbms", v => dbType = Int32.Parse(v));               

        x.Service<DataReplicator>(r =>
        {
            r.ConstructUsing(replicate => new DataReplicator(hostName, dbName, user, password, port, tableName, dbType));
            r.WhenStarted(replicate => replicate.Start());
            r.WhenStopped(replicate => replicate.Stop());
        });

        x.RunAsLocalSystem();

        x.SetServiceName("TopShelfDataReplicator");
        x.SetDisplayName("TopShelf Data Replicator");
        x.SetDescription("Replicate the local data to the network");
        x.StartAutomatically();
    });

    int exitValue = (int)Convert.ChangeType(exitCode, exitCode.GetTypeCode());
    Environment.ExitCode = exitValue;
}
```

Comment: I tried `DataReplicator.exe install -h:localhost -d:networkdatabase -U:root -pwd:testpwd -tbl:testtable -dbms:1 -p:3306` and `DataReplicator.exe install start -h:localhost -d:networkdatabase -U:root -pwd:testpwd -tbl:testtable -dbms:1 -p:3306`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set Service Start Parameter using Topshelf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32892760/set-service-start-parameter-using-topshelf)

Comment: Yes, I just added the project from the link: [Set Service Start Parameter using Topshelf](https://github.com/r1pper/Topshelf.StartParameters) and it seems to be working. Just be cautious, the parameters that you passed when you install will not be overwritten even if you stop and start the service by typing another value on that parameter `sc.exe servicename start -param1 "value1"`. You need to stop and install again.